# Grid no R não funciona

Tags: r, grid

Olá, estou tentando criar um gráfico com o seguinte código:

```
boxplot(covid_DF$obitosNovos ~ month(covid_DF$data),
        main="Média de obitos novos por mês no Distrito Federal",
        xlab="Mês",
        ylab="Quantidade de casos novos",
        col="#db525a",
        border="#050627"
)
```

O gráfico aparece certinho, porém quando tento botar a função para adicionar um grid para tornar a visualização por parte do usuário mais fácil:

```
boxplot(covid_DF$obitosNovos ~ month(covid_DF$data),
        main="Média de obitos novos por mês no Distrito Federal",
        xlab="Mês",
        ylab="Quantidade de casos novos",
        col="#db525a",
        border="#050627",
        panel.first = grid()
)
```

Adicionando a funcao de grid no final não funciona. Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, dê uma olhada [neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) (principalmente no uso da função `dput`) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O argumento `panel.first` é avaliado de forma preguiçosa ("lazy"), o que traz algumas limitações. Uma delas é que ele não funciona quando se usa fórmula para especificar o gráfico. A solução mais simples para ter a grade no fundo nesses casos é gerar o gráfico, adicionar a grade e plotar o gráfico de novo por cima.

Como sua pergunta não depende dos seus dados e para facilitar a reprodução, usei dados genéricos:

```
# Dados de exemplo
set.seed(732)
df <- data.frame(
  x = rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 20),
  y = rnorm(80, 20))

boxplot(y ~ x, df)
grid()
boxplot(y ~ x, df, col = "white", add = TRUE)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]